# How can i solve this equation $|x|\hat x= 1991x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found this problem in an old exam and i want to know how to do it, since i couldn't at the time, it's in spanish so i'll leave my translation and the original:

Solve this equation $|x|\hat x= 1991x$. Here $|x|$ is the biggest integer less than or equal than $x$, and $\hat x=x-|x|$, ie, it's the fractionary part of $x$.

---

*Resuelve la ecuacion $|x|\hat x= 1991x$. Aquí $|x|$ denota al mayor entero menor o igual que $x$, y $\hat x=x-|x|$, es decir, es la parte fraccionaria de $x$.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity denote $\hat x=x-|x|=a$. Then rewrite the equation as $$(x-a)a=1991x.$$ Find $x$:$$x=\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ a-1991 } .$$ We know $a<1$, hence $-1<x\le0.$ As a result $ x-a=\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor=-1$ . By solving $$-a=1991(a-1)$$ we get $a=\frac{1991}{1992}$. We know $x-a=-1$, so $x=-\frac{1}{1992}$

Answer (score 4):

There is the obvious solution $x=0$. There are no positive solutions, since it is clear that the left side is smaller than the right side when $x$ is positive.

Now look for negative solutions. Let $x$ be equal to $-n+r$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $0\le r\lt 1$. Then $\lfloor x\rfloor=-n$. (I am using $r$ as the name for the *parte fraccionaria* and $-n$ instead of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ because too many $x$'s floating around confuses me.)

Your equation becomes
$(-n)(r)=1991(-n+r)$. That manipulates to $r=\frac{1991n}{n+1991}$. This is less than $1$ only at the positive integer $n=1$.  Thus $x=-1+\frac{1991}{1992}=-\frac{1}{1992}$.